# What happens when someone needs one very specific feature?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, questions

I agree with the quality standards that have been outlined so far but I think there's a problem with people understanding the difference between a low quality question and a brief question.

There's a big difference between "I need an IDE." and "I need a plugin for this specific IDE that does this one specific task in this specific way (with examples)." The latter is getting treated like the former either because the reviewer doesn't know the software well enough or because the asker doesn't know enough to provide more information. Either way a terse request for more requirements isn't exactly helpful.

There's plenty of information on what constitutes a good question. Can we get some information on when and how to ask for more information?

Note:

We had this problem on Christianity.SE. It has a lot of the same problems with subjective questions and answers that this site has. Over there we came up with a fairly concise set of guidelines on helpful criticism and I think something similar would help here.

Comment: I'm certainly guilty of relating short <-> low quality, and I bet many others are too.

Comment: Should we continue this discussion here? **[Okay to ask for software having one feature?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/691/is-it-ok-to-ask-for-a-software-having-a-particular-feature)**

Comment: I think that question is about closing questions. I'm looking for answers on how and when to comment.

Comment: @crownjewel82 I was aiming at asking something similar, as 2 of my answers on a question asking for just 1 feature got deleted (the question was put on hold too) and I suspect that brevity got associated with low-quality and/or broadness. But I guess it's good to rephrase the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of a good question with one feature request that is so specific that others are not needed:

[Program to search EULA contracts for problems](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1750/83)

We want to make sure that questions are not too broad.  However, some tasks are so specific by themselves that other feature constraints are not needed to keep the question from being too broad.

This will always be a judgement call.  We can't (and shouldn't) specify a rule that spells out the minimum number of required features for a question.  Before voting to close a question for being too broad, ask yourself if it really is too broad, or if you just have that impression because it doesn't have a big feature list.